# Css change parent after child focus

Tags: html, css

I need add border to div after focus on child element:

**html**

```
<div class="header_search col-lg-5">
   <form role="form" action="hledat.php" method="get">
      <input type="text">
   </form>
</div>
```

**css**

```
 .header_search {
        border: 0px;
    }

.header_search input:focus < div {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

but that is not working

Comment: `<` is invalid, also looks like you're encountering the problem which has been asked thousands of times called ***Is there a parent selector in CSS3?***

Comment: http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex

Answer (score 3):

You can now do this in pure CSS so no JavaScript is needed.

The new CSS pseudo-class `:focus-within` would help for cases like this and will help with accessibility when people use tabbing for navigating, common when using screen readers.

```
.header_search:focus-within {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

---

> The :focus-within pseudo-class matches elements that either themselves
>   match :focus or that have descendants which match :focus.

You can check which browsers support this http://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within

Answer (score -1):

I'm a little altered your example

[Live Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lpLIc)

**HTML**

```
<div class="header_search col-lg-5">
   <form role="form" action="hledat.php" method="get">
      <input type="text">
   </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header_search {
        border: 0px;
    }

.header_search input:focus {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately the OP wants to style the border ***of the parent div***, not of the input.

Comment: This is still only changing the properties of the child, not the parent.